# What is the effect of & in c++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, pass-by-reference

```
template <typename T>
const T& longestOfTheThree(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c){
    T longest = a;
    if (longest.length < b.length){longest = b;}
    if (longest.length < c.length){longest = c;}
    return longest; 
}
```

Can someone explain why `const T&` (specifically the `&` before `longestOfTheThree`) is invalid? Why does the code only compile if I remove the `&`?

This code compiles:

```
template <typename T>
const T longestOfTheThree(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c){
    T longest = a;
    if (longest.length < b.length){longest = b;}
    if (longest.length < c.length){longest = c;}
    return longest; 
}
```

Comment: For the same reason its invalid in a non-template function: You shall not return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: The meaning is the same as in non-template code - in your example, the function accepts three arguments by `const` reference, and returns a `const` reference.   The code is invalid on return since `longest` is a local variable, with automatic storage duration, so ceases to exist when the function returns.  Returning a reference to something that no longer exists would cause (if it was allowed) undefined behaviour (since, if the caller uses the reference, it would access a variable that no longer exists).

Comment: @tkausl typically that doesn't cause a compilation error (although OP might have configured the compiler to report an error for it -- probably not a bad idea!)

Comment: Please include the compiler error message when asking a question about why code does not compile  (and minimum code needed to reproduce the compilation error)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a reference to an ASDV ("stack" variable). That doesn't work: `longest` is destructed before return.

If you'd like to return a reference, you can do, for example:

```
template <typename T>
const T& longestOfTheThree(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c){
    if (a.length < b.length) {
        if (b.length < c.length) { return c; }
        return b;
    } else /* !(a.length < b.length) */ {
        if (a.length < c.length) { return c; }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Or, if you'd like to keep `longest`, you can have a pointer:

```
template <typename T>
const T& longestOfTheThree(const T& a, const T& b, const T& c){
    const T* longest = &a;
    if (longest->length < b.length) { longest = &b; }
    if (longest->length < c.length) { longest = &c; }
    return *longest;
}
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't really work.  "longest" isn't defined 1st, and 2nd being that "a" is never compared to  (and 3rdly, if c > b > longest, it would just return b, and not c)

Comment: @UKMonkey Indeed, fixed, thanks.

Comment: What does `ASDV` stand for?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Automatic Storage Duration Variable. Many refer to them as 'stack' variables, but stack is not part of the standard.

Comment: Hmm, never seen this abbreviation before.